# Run software intended for Windows XP on Windows 10 - Software requires GPIB card

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, compatibility, legacy

I am trying to run old software that is intended to run on Windows XP on Windows 10 instead. This software requires a [General Purpose Interface Bus (GPIB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE-488) card which connects a mechanical machine. The Windows 10 computer reports that no machine is recognized and so I think the GPIB card is not being seen.

I have tried adjusting compatibility settings for the software and using a virtual machine but neither work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It won't work. It must be installed in the host system in order to have access to the hardware. In a VM at best the device would have to be passed to the VM but that is only possible, with most hypervisors, with (some) USB devices.

Comment: How does the GPIB connect to the computer USB,com,parrellel port, or something else?

Comment: There are GPBI to USB interfaces.  I showed and example in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since the software will not install / run in Windows 10 (not much XP software will), then your options are limited.  XP will not run on a modern machine.

Use a good Virtual Machine App (I use VMware), make an XP Virtual Machine (I have one here).

Then see if you can use Pass Through to install the card in the Virtual Machine.

If this does not work, you are out of luck.

If a new machine is out of the question, you can consider VMWware ESX (bare metal platform) and see if XP runs on that (I do not know for sure) because ESX allows a guest to use host hardware.

Depending on the machine, you may be able to use a GPIB to USB interface which in turn may allow pass through.

Here is an example.

[GPIB to USB interface](https://www.valuetronics.com/product/gpib-usb-a-national-instruments-gpib-adapter-used?gclid=Cj0KCQiAr8eqBhD3ARIsAIe-buPpk-wFbzvchvFEN93VBF4viHv4C_0pSoztAlLpN4bkNEXb-ws7rakaAu4VEALw_wcB)